# Calcular média e filtrar por valores acima desta média

Tags: mysql, sql

Gostaria de fazer um média dos valores gastos por todos os clientes. Depois listar os nomes dos clientes que gastaram acima da média (pode ser utilizando `inner join`, mas com sub consulta):

```
SELECT a.primeiro_nome, AVG(b.valor) AS media
    FROM cliente AS a
    INNER JOIN pagamento AS b ON (a.cliente_id = b.cliente_id)
    GROUP BY a.cliente_id
      HAVING media > (SELECT 
        AVG(valor)
         FROM pagamento);
```

Comment: Seja bem vindo Felipe, tente trazer o máximo de detalhes na sua pergunta, mostrando até que ponto está seu código atual e estrutura de tabelas.

Comment: Felipe Boa noite! se puder detalhar melhor com códigos fica mais fácil para ajuda-lo.

Comment: Sua query apresentou algum problema?

Comment: Precisava de uma coisa mais especifica

Answer (score 0):

Calcule a média geral (média das médias) e depois compare com a média dos clientes

```
  SELECT a.primeiro_nome
        FROM cliente AS a
        INNER JOIN pagamento AS b ON (a.cliente_id = b.cliente_id)
        GROUP BY a.cliente_id
        having avg(b.valor) > (select avg(media) 
                               from
                               (
                                SELECT a.primeiro_nome, AVG(b.valor) media
                                INNER JOIN pagamento AS b ON (a.cliente_id = b.cliente_id)
                                GROUP BY a.cliente_id
                                ) media_geral)
```